# SiteEdit v1.3 with Tridion 2011SP1 not working

Tags: siteedit

The CM server contains: SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 and SiteEdit 2009 SP3. Since the templates are VBScript and using the 'old' SiteEdit, SiteEdit 1.3 SP1 is also installed. All according to the manuals.

The CM database was a 2009 GA version, which has been migrated to 2011 SP1 HR1. That's why SiteEdit v1.3 DLL is installed and registered. (SiteEdit and SiteEdit2 objects exists)

On the CM server, Tridion uses port 80, SiteEdit 2009 uses port 84.

BTW: It is not possible to install SiteEdit 1.3 SP1 on the CM machine because the installer doesn't recognize the CM website.

The problem is that the SiteEdit functionality is not shown nor working on the Presentation Server.

The PS server is a separate machine, with IIS7.5 and WebSphere. IIS has the /Images folder as its root, and therefore only serving the binaries. The IBM WebSphere plugin to redirect all traffic (for JSP, JS, CSS, etc.) to the WebSphere applicatie is installed. The staging website runs on port 81.

A simple plain JSP testpage is published to the PS server and available on port 81.

The source of the published page on the staging website contains the code:

```
<script defer="defer" id="_SE_Script" SRC="/SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js" SE="http://CM:84/|tcm:127-462398-64|1|tcm:0-134-65537|1|1|1|0|1|#AAAAAA|black|#EECCCC|red|#EEAAAA|#00AA00|#AAEEAA"></script>
```

The tcm id's of the page and the publication target are correct.

There is of course no /SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js on the PS server....

Since I'm writing this, I suspect that the SE URL should be something like, SRC="http://CM:84/SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js" because that URL is a valid URL for the CM server.

In IIS Manager > Sites > SiteEdit 2009 SP3 > has virtual directory /SiteEdit which points to the SiteEdit folder within the SiteEdit 2009 folder.

The old 2009 GA server has a physical file called /SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js

There a several web.config's edited, I'll guess there too big and too much to display here.

The SiteEdit 2009 web.config has a:

```
<add key="UrlToHide" value="/.*SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js"/>
```

Any tips for debugging and solving this issue?

The culprit is the /SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js which doesn't exists on the PS server (in this case the WebSphere Application Server).

**Update 2013-06-25:**

Changed the SiteEdit URL on the Presentation Server, from relative /SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js to absolute: CM:84/SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js (http:// in front of CM:84 is not accepted by StackExchange).

So the script tag reads:

```
<script defer="defer" id="_SE_Script" SRC="http://cms:84/SiteEdit/SiteEdit.js" ... />
```

Calling this absolute URL via Internet Explorer on the PS machine or the CM machine results in http error 503 server unavailable.

Comment: Changing that URL to an absolute URL should make no different **if you access the page through the SiteEdit proxy** (which you are running on port 84). When you access the page through the SiteEdit proxy, that will simply absorb the request for `/SiteEdit/EditEdit.js` (as Peter says) and return a 404. This is normal behavior for you combination (SiteEdit 1.3 building blocks with a SiteEdit 2009 front-end), so please ignore that part in your further analysis. The 503 error typically comes with more details in the Windows event viewer.

Comment: Windows Actions Service was not started :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what the issue is here. But I can say that you don't need or want the SiteEdit.js file to be there physically. On the PS side, you only want SiteEdit 2009 SP3.

It is backwards compatible for the markup, and it will ignore the old request to the SiteEdit.js file as long as you keep that "UrlToHide" setting as the default.

Hopefully that's cleared up the question of SiteEdit.js.

As to why the button doesn't show up (that is what you mean, right?), this is usually because of accessing the staging URL when you should be accessing the SiteEdit proxy web service.

Comment: Do you mean with "On the PS side, you only want SiteEdit 2009 SP3" that a page should contain the <script ... src="http://cm:84/"...> and nothing more?

Comment: Not exactly. I meant that you shouldn't install 1.3 on your presentation servers and you shouldn't have the SiteEdit.js file there (but it won't matter if you do so long as you have the UrlToHide setting set to ignore it)

Comment: Updated my post, get http error 503 service unavailble.